# Не загружаются несколько изображений в laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, изображения

Уже два дня не могу разобраться почему не получается загрузить несколько файлов. Вот часть контроллера, отвечающая за загрузку.

```
if($request->hasfile('petimage')){
 $petimages = $request->file('petimage'); 
    foreach($petimages as $petimage){
$destinationPath='uploads/petimages'; 
$ext = $petimage->extension(); 
$filename = str_random(20).'.'.$ext; 
$resizedImg = Image::make($petimage)->insert('uploads/logo.png')->resize(750,500); 
$resizedImg->save($destinationPath.'/'.$filename); 
Album::create([ 
'image_url'=> $filename, 
'pets_id'=>$pet->id, 
'user_id'=>$user_id, 
'company_id'=> $company_id ]); } return redirect()->back();  }
```

С циклом изображения не загружаются, но без него все работает:

```
if($request->hasfile('petimage')){ 
$petimage = $request->file('petimage');
$destinationPath='uploads/petimages'; 
$ext = $petimage->extension(); 
$filename = time().'.'.$ext; 
$resizedImg = Image::make($petimage)->insert('uploads/logo.png')->resize(750,500); 
$resizedImg->save($destinationPath.'/'.$filename); 
Album::create([ 
'image_url'=> $filename, 
'pets_id'=>$pet->id, 
'user_id'=>$user_id, 
'company_id'=> $company_id ]); } return redirect()->back();
```

Сам инпут

```
<form action="{{route('pets.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">@csrf
   <div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="petimage[]" multiple>
       </div>
       </form>
```

Собственно, вопрос: что не так и как исправить чтобы можно было загружать несколько изображений?

PS. Это благотворительный проект, а я не разработчик. Так что заранее извиняюсь если задаю очень глупый вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

`$petimages = $request->file('petimage'); 
    foreach($petimages as $petimage){`

замените на

`/** var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $petimage */
   foreach ($request->petimage as $petimage) {`

Если не поможет - попробуйте в контроллере выполнить `dd($request)` и посмотреть где Ваши файлы массивом сидят. По идее должен быть массив объектов UploadedFile по количеству загружаемых файлов.

Документация: [Laravel Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#files), [Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php).

Comment: Не помогает к сожалению, это был самый первый вариант. Пока что просто кучу инпутов сделал для 10 файлов.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, если у вас Laravel 5.8

```
collect($request->images)->each(function ($image) {
    return $image->store('images', 'public');
});
```